# Sampling analog signal with python; problems with understanding fundamentals

Tags: python, analog-to-digital

I would like to sample an analog 5kHz signal with a 50MHz sample rate. I want to do this with python so I can see if this sort of sample rate is enough for my needs. But I couldn't wrap my head around the problem.

I am so used to Simulink where I can have a continuous signal which I can move to the workspace and sample easily. Now in python, what I am struggling with is producing an "analog" signal. I need to have the analog signal so that I can sample it at 50 Megs to see the performance of the digitization.

What am I missing?

Edit: I have a capacitor discharge that takes 200 usecs. I will be acquiring this signal with hardware. But before selecting the hardware I wanted to see if 50 Msps is a sufficient sampling rate for my requirements.

Comment: Could be, of course. I am struggling to replicate that analog signal that is available in Simulink. I couldn't find a way to produce an analog signal, or even if it is possible. Do you have any recommendations for me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with an example continuous-time signal that you wish to sample -- i.e. if you just want $sin(2 \pi 5\mathrm{kHz} t)$, then there it is.  Note that Simulink doesn't generate continuous-time signals -- it just generates a function of time, then calculates that function for the time intervals it's decided it needs to sample.

Comment: Edited the question. sin(2π5kHzt) this is what I tried as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and welcome to SE.SP!

You need to learn the difference between *analog* and *digital* signals. You can google this of course.
In a nutshell, an analog signal is a **continuous** signal representing some other quantity, i.e., *analogous* to another quantity (source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_signal)). You could coarsely say that analog signals only exist in the physical world. Sound, light, voltage, temperature: these are signals that are *continuous* in time.

When we want to analyze an analog signal with digital devices such as computers, that can only represent signals as a set of **discrete** (the opposite of continuous) numbers,  we need to [*sample*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)) this signal through the use of an **ADC** (**Analog** to **Digital** Converter), the result being a **sequence of samples** that the computer can store.

What you're asking is therefore impossible. Once the signal is in computer memory, it's already sampled. It's not continuous anymore, it's **digital**.

As such, in your case, the 5KHz signal you mention is either already sampled at some sampling frequency defined by whatever ADC was used to convert the **analog representation** of its physical quantity into a **digital representation** through **sampling**, or it has been generated by software (see @Tim Wescott's comment on your OP).

What you *might* be trying to do is to *resample* your signal, i.e modifying the sampling rate, but I won't go further into this since you really need to understand the absolute basics first.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

**EDIT: Sampling rate requirements**
You need a sampling rate that's AT LEAST twice your signal's bandwidth of interest ([Nyquist-Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)). So if you're interested in a 5KHz signal, 50MHz is overkill. In fact, the theory would tell you that a sampling rate of 10KHz is enough. Of course that's the theory, in practice you'd want to sample at a rate higher than that. Not sure what sampling rates your ADC supports, but 16KHz is a typical one, and in your case would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may have used incorrect terms. I have edited the question now. I mainly have a 200 usec discharge I want to capture. I am trying to decide on a sampling rate for hardware. I wanted to do some simulations in this regard

Comment: @Guarneer Edited my answer in this regard

Comment: Yes I am aware of the Nyquist rule but I have strict requirements so I need to know many data point during the discharge.

Comment: what are your "strict requirements"? The answer to your original question as stated is just a resounding YES, 50MHz sample rate is ENOUGH to capture a 5KHz signal.  But I don't think that's what you actually mean to ask. A discharge of $200\mu s$ would only contain one period of a 5KHz signal. Your question needs to be re-written. As it is, there's not much we can help you with.

Comment: If you know your signal's bandwidth, and you know the nyquist rule, then what else do you need?